# java processbuilder open a text file for reading data

Tags: java, c, process

I have a file lets say "test.txt", (same directory as java program) that has numbers on it as seen below. My aim is to start a process builder which reads the data from the file then I'm going to paint it to a java JPanel.

1. I understand to read the data from the text file, I will need to read the input stream. **question 1: How can I read line by line? So after the first line has read, the process builder goes to the next?**
2. I'm puzzled on how to actually start a process like this. i.e **Q2: How can I open a text file using processBuilder?**

For the second question I've tried something like this. Nothing happens on screen as I haven't instructed anything to happen, but is it on the right track?

```
   //get data back
    public void returnData ()
    {   
    try {
    ProcessBuilder pb;
    pb = new ProcessBuilder("test.txt");
    Process runCode = pb.start();
    runCode.waitFor();
    }
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException exp) {
        System.out.println(exp);
    }
    }
```

test.txt

```
0
1
3
5
2
3
```

Comment: 1- [Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/); 2- I wouldn't, but you could use [Dealtop#open or Desktop#edit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html); If your'e really keen on trying to use ProcessBuilder, then you will need to know the executable command that can open the text file and pass it as parameter to that command...and possibly read the InputStream from the Process...

Answer (score 0):

You would need a program that sends the file to standard out such as 
For windows:

```
type filename
```

For Unix

```
cat filename
```

Then execute this command using the ProcessBuilder.
InputStreamReader to read the stream and BufferedReader to read line by line.

```
BufferedReader in
       = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processstream));
in.readLine ();
```

This is a really platform dependent way to do it when basic java IO would do it in a portable way.

FileReader to access the file and BufferedReader to read line by line.

```
BufferedReader in
             = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.in"));
in.readLine ();
```

Comment: Thanks I shall give it a go and see how it goes and let you know